# Rxjs timeout() is throwing error for some Future Dates

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Rxjs timeout() is not working properly for some **Days** or **Timestamp**

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

const seconds = interval(1000);

seconds.pipe(
  // Present Date (Thu Mar 19 2020 14:40:58) => 1584628858530
  // to UTC time & date: (Wed Dec 30 2020 18:30:00) => 1609353000000-------Not working
  // to UTC time & date: (Mon Dec 30 2030 18:30:00) => 1924885800000-------Working
  timeout(new Date(1609353000000)), // replace timestamp
)
.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value), 
    err => console.log(err)
);
```

Click [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout) for Original Documentation. Check Example 2..

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: throwing error for date Wed Dec 30 **2020** 18:30:00 but working fine with Mon Dec 30 **2030** 18:30:00

Comment: There has been an issue on GitHub for a while with this problem https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3015

Comment: Thank you so much @martin for the link..